# Exporting MYSQL Table to file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, into-outfile

I got this code on this website, but I can't get it working.

```
$file = 'backups/mytable.sql'; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '".$file."' FROM ##TABLE##");
```

I then modified it:

```
$file = "Backups/mytable.sql"; 
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '".$file."' FROM comments") or die ("Query Died: Exporting");
```

The query just dies, no PHP error. I am using XAMPP.

Comment: what did `echo mysql_error();` give you ?

Comment: if you are running this code on a *nix like environment backups and Backups are different directories (and maybe the second one does not exist)

Comment: Currnetly this is only run on my local Windows 7 Machine using XAMPP. mysqli_error() shows nothing, stays blank.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission to do this?

The priviledge attribute is 'FILE' and it works both ways, reading from and writing to files.

Comment: Where do I check if I do have privilidg, I am new to php and only recently finished my Guide, I couldn't find that in my guide.

Comment: I check now in PHPMYADMIN, under privileges, under the DATA column, File is checked.